# Change blank spaces with underscores in Bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to write a script in Bash that:

1. Takes a file as an input.
2. If the file name has any blank space it changes it with an underscore.

My first question is: can a Bash script take arguments as input or any input has to be provided once the script is running by means of the read command? The other question would be how to use the `mv` command to perform point 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script could be simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

mv "$1" "$(sed 's/ \{1,\}/_/g' <<<"$1")"
```

Use it like `script.sh file\ name`. The file `file name` will be renamed to `file_name`.

As [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) has pointed out in the comments (thanks), if you are using bash it is also possible to use the built-in character substitution:

```
mv "$1" "${1// /_}"
```

The behaviour of this is slightly different, as it will replace every individual space with an underscore, whereas the approach using sed also squashes groups of spaces into a single underscore. If you enable extended globbing, you can make this version behave the same as the one using sed:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv "$1" "${1//+( )/_}"
```

Depending on whether you are looking to replace space characters  or all kinds of white space (like tabs, newlines, etc.), you may want to use `[[:space:]]` rather than  in each of these examples.

Comment: Please, use Bash! `mv "$1" "${1//[[:space:]]/_}"`. No need to invoque `sed` for this.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf make your comment an answer so i can upvote it :)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, your version will happily replace other white space characters.  In my answer I'm replacing only spaces with the same construct. -- as it was pointed out I missed that particular requirement, fixing my answer.

Comment: @galaxy: isn't this the OP's requirement? _If the file name has any blank space it changes it with an underscore._

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, actually RedX didn't post any answers here yet :)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks for your suggestion, I've edited my answer to include something similar.

Comment: To obtain the same behavior as `sed`: `mv "$1" "${1//+([[:space:]])/_}"`. This might need `shopt -s extglob` if `extglob` is unset.

Comment: Also, you `sed` statement could be written as `s/\s\+/_/g` or `s/\ \+/_/g` instead of the (arguably) ugly `\{1,\}`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I thought I was careful to quote where necessary but I guess that it can't hurt to add extra ones. I went with the `\{1,\}` as I thought that it was the most portable approach.

Comment: Without these quotes, the command is still subject to pathname expansion… or even word splitting as you don't handle tabs and newlines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked smoothly. I'll take a careful look throughout the discussion to learn the pros and cons of each implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course bash scripts can be provided with arguments.  I'd suggest to read at least bash manual (man bash) and it will answer most of your questions.

Re: your actual task - it would really help to know your OS.  If you are running this on *nix something like the following would solve your issue:

```
$ touch "example file 1" "example  file  2"
$ ls -ld example*
-rw------- 1 user group 0 Oct 29 00:06 example  file  2
-rw------- 1 user group 0 Oct 29 00:06 example file 1
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '* *' -print0 | xargs -0i /bin/bash -c 'F="{}" ; mv -iv "$F" "${F//[[:space:]]/_}"'
'./example  file  2' -> './example__file__2'
'./example file 1' -> './example_file_1'
$ ls -ld example*
-rw------- 1 user group 0 Oct 29 00:06 example__file__2
-rw------- 1 user group 0 Oct 29 00:06 example_file_1
$
```

Comment: You don't need `xargs`: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '* *' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0// /_}"' {} \;`. (Also used `bash`, since my `sh` doesn't support this expansion).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Yes, I do, since -execdir is a GNU extension and not available everywhere, so to play safe (OP didn't mention what OS they are running) I decided to go for xargs :) -- thanks for pointing out re: sh, it's a valid point.

Comment: `-execdir` _is not a GNU extension_ (you're not the first one who claims this… where did you get this from?). Anyway, `-exec` will do the job as well.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, well, I can't quickly locate anything on this, but I remember that in 2005-2006 there were Linux distros that didn't support -execdir, hence the habit :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My intention is to read much more about bash scripting, of course.

Comment: Just to complete the conversation on the `-execdir` option being non-standard - POSIX knows nothing about `-execdir`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html